# Informix 11.70.FC8GE - How to pass a LIST data type to a SPL using a SELECT

Tags: informix, sqldatatypes, spl

I saw another question concerning pushing SET data types to c# code, but it didn't really answer what I was trying to do.

I am trying to pass a LIST data type to a SPL using a select.  I know in a SPL a LIST can be DEFINED and set as such:

```
DEFINE a LIST(INTEGER NOT NULL);
LET a = LIST{(SELECT unique b from numberTable)};
```

I also know that a list can be sent to a SPL if its variable is a LIST.

```
execute procedure someProc(LIST{1,2,3});
```

Knowing these two things I want to try to create a LIST from a SELECT for the variable.

```
execute procedure someProc(LIST{(SELECT unique b from numberTable)});
```

So I created a small test case.

```
create table tab1 (a int);

insert into tab1 values (1);
insert into tab1 values (2);
insert into tab1 values (3);

create procedure retInt(c LIST(INTEGER NOT NULL))
RETURNING INTEGER;

DEFINE b INTEGER;

FOREACH SELECT * INTO b from TABLE(c)
        return b with RESUME;
end FOREACH

end procedure;

-- Works
execute procedure retInt(LIST{1,2,3});

-- Doesn't work
-- returns 284: A subquery has returned not exactly one row.
execute procedure retInt(LIST{(SELECT a from tab1)});
```

I also tried type cast the select like this

```
execute procedure retInt((SELECT a from tab1)::LIST(INTEGER NOT NULL));
```

Needless to say that created a syntax error.

I may be trying to do something that isn't possible.  Looking through IBM's documentation I did not find anything, however sometimes I feel that their documentation can be difficult to use.

Any thoughts?

Thank you in advance,
Caton

Answer (score 2):

In Informix you cannot build a LIST directly from a SELECT statement unless the select returns exactly 1 row.
I suspect that in the example that you gave the query is returning exactly 1 row and the LIST is created.

Informix won't let you create a LIST from a SELECT that returns multiple rows, but it accepts creating a MULTISET from a SELECT that returns multiple rows, that then can be cast to a LIST.

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE retInt((MULTISET(SELECT ITEM a FROM tab1)::LIST(INTEGER NOT NULL)));
```

The keyword ITEM is required to create a MULTISET of INTEGER values, instead of a multiset of ROW values.